# Responsive columns and expandable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i created a codepen here
http://codepen.io/eryonn/pen/ZLXLBX
in which i would keep the responsive layout with 2 columns but when i i click "open" in one of the div it should expand in height for other 100px. Is is possible? Is it possible using this kind of structure of the page? Anyway this is the code:

```
<div ng-controller="gridListDemoCtrl as vm" flex="" ng-cloak="" class="gridListdemoDynamicTiles" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-grid-list md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-gt-md="2" md-row-height-gt-md="3:1" md-row-height="4:3" md-gutter="8px" md-gutter-gt-sm="4px">

    <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="tile in vm.tiles" md-rowspan="{{tile.span.row}}" md-colspan="{{tile.span.col}}" md-colspan-sm="1">
      <md-card layout-fill ng-class="tile.background">
        <md-card-title>
          <md-card-title-text>
            <span class="md-headline">Action buttons</span>
          </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-button type="button" data-ng-if="tile.showDetails" data-ng-click="tile.showDetails = false">
          Close
        </md-button>
        <md-button type="button" data-ng-if="!tile.showDetails"  ng-click="tiles.showDetailsFnt(tile)">
          Open
        </md-button>
      </md-card>
    </md-grid-tile>
  </md-grid-list>
</div>
```

Js

```
angular
  .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('gridListDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.tiles = {
       showDetails: false,
       showDetailsFnt: function(tile) {
         console.log(tile);
         tile.showDetails = true;
       }
     };
    this.tiles = buildGridModel({
            icon : "avatar:svg-",
            title: "Svg-",
            background: ""
          });

    function buildGridModel(tileTmpl){
      var it, results = [ ];

      for (var j=0; j<11; j++) {

        it = angular.extend({},tileTmpl);
        it.icon  = it.icon + (j+1);
        it.title = it.title + (j+1);
        it.span  = { row : 1, col : 1 };

        switch(j+1) {
          case 1:it.background = "red";break;
          case 2: it.background = "green";         break;
          case 3: it.background = "darkBlue";      break;
          case 4:it.background = "blue";break;
          case 5:it.background = "yellow";break;
          case 6: it.background = "pink";          break;
          case 7: it.background = "darkBlue";      break;
          case 8: it.background = "purple";        break;
          case 9: it.background = "deepBlue";      break;
          case 10: it.background = "lightPurple";  break;
          case 11: it.background = "yellow";       break;
        }

        results.push(it);
      }
      return results;
    }
  })
  .config( function( $mdIconProvider ){
    $mdIconProvider.iconSet("avatar", 'icons/avatar-icons.svg', 128);
  });
```

Comment: When you click open, you want the divs height to increase by 100px?

Comment: Yes exactly. That div of course

Comment: @JoshSpearsany idea?

Comment: This is so over-engineered but I'm not familiar with angular. Would you care to see a non-angular solution?

Comment: hmmm.. let's see. maybe i can convert it in angular.. maybe! Let's see for now

Comment: @End.Game Well It's hard to adjust the height of the divs due to your structure not being built properly with CSS, but you can target the element by `$event`. Ill put in in the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the click `$event` into the functions parameter, so you can access the div, and edit it with jQuery Lite.

```
$scope.tiles = {
  showDetails: false,
  showDetailsFnt: function($event, tile) {  
    angular.element($event.currentTarget.parentElement).addClass('extended');
  }
};
```

Pass the `$event` in the DOM.

```
<md-button type="button" data-ng-if="!tile.showDetails"  ng-click="tiles.showDetailsFnt($event, tile)">
   Open
 </md-button>
```

You will have to edit your CSS for the `.extended` class now, it might be tricky with your layout structure. But thats how you can change the height of the div on click, by adding classes.

```
.extended {
  height: 200px; // Or whatever
}
```